# Arclength of a pipe length between two different elevations

Tags: fluid-mechanics, civil-engineering

I am trying to find the arclength and max height of a pipe between two reservoirs A and B. The height of A is 0.4km and the height of B is 0.6km.

The change in elevation is given by $z^* = a + bx^* + c(x^*)^2$

$z^* = z/0.2km$ and $x^* = x/400 km$

x is the horizontal distance from A and 400 is the horizontal distance from A and B.

The maximum pipe elevation is $x^* = 0.6$

I can't seem to find the arclength between A and B. Would it be roughly similar to 400 km (the length from A to B) given that change in height is only 0.2 km and thus could be negligible? Furthermore, how might I go about finding max length?

Answer (score 1):

The arc length (AL) of a function z(x) is given by:

$$AL = \int_{x_A}^{x_B}\sqrt{1+\left[z'(x)\right]^2}dx$$

so you need to make the proper conversion and solve the integral (This seems to me like a homework exercise, so I won't provide the numerical solution until I've seen what you've tried so far).